# Traceroute command last hop cannot be reached

Tags: traceroute, next-hop

By running the traceroute command below I obtained this output:

traceroute www.google.com -q 3 -m 60
traceroute to www.google.com (172.217.169.36), 60 hops max, 60 byte packets

```
 1  gateway (10.81.62.1)  0.380 ms  0.317 ms  0.274 ms
 2  192.168.80.9 (192.168.80.9)  0.165 ms  0.344 ms  0.296 ms
 3  192.168.80.1 (192.168.80.1)  0.302 ms  0.298 ms  0.284 ms
 4  192.168.210.2 (192.168.210.2)  0.404 ms  0.413 ms  0.411 ms
 5  192.168.210.6 (192.168.210.6)  3.322 ms  3.286 ms  3.322 ms
 6  xe-5-0-0.londpg-ban1.ja.net (146.97.137.37)  1.233 ms  1.214 ms  1.119 ms
 7  ae26.londpg-sbr2.ja.net (146.97.35.233)  1.433 ms  1.414 ms  1.409 ms
 8  ae29.londhx-sbr1.ja.net (146.97.33.1)  1.905 ms  1.885 ms  1.859 ms
 9  193.62.157.22 (193.62.157.22)  2.308 ms  3.439 ms  3.545 ms
10  * * *
11  172.253.50.222 (172.253.50.222)  3.276 ms 108.170.238.116 
(108.170.238.116)  2.856 ms 216.239.58.222 (216.239.58.222)  4.139 ms
12  172.253.66.89 (172.253.66.89)  4.166 ms 172.253.66.87 (172.253.66.87)  4.391 ms 108.170.246.144 (108.170.246.144)  4.955 ms
13  64.233.175.113 (64.233.175.113)  3.686 ms lhr48s08-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.169.36)  3.748 ms  3.535 ms
```

After hop 13 it stopped. Does that mean it reached it target destination?
When pasting the IP address from hop 13 in the browser it couldn't connect. Shouldn't this be the ip address of one of the google servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traceroute can be used to spy out a network. There are usually 2 ways, companies deal with blocking it.

Fist: Devices will be configured to not reply to TTL=0 packets. But they will still allow other devices to send TTL=0 packets thru the device itself (seen in your example as step 10)

Second: Devices wont reply to TTL=0 packets and it will block every TTL=0 message traversing the device to hide sensitive information from the LAN network (seen in your example as step 13).

So your traceroute does not know that the device blocks all the replies, so it keeps on sending more to a maximum of 60 hops. These requests will all time out because of the configuration on device at step 13.

Comment: Some companies will also look for traceroute by looking for a low TTL value and sending the packets on a wild goose chase in a different direction, confusing the results.

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean it reached it target destination?

Yes - as far as you can tell by using traceroute.

> When pasting the IP address from hop 13 in the browser it couldn't connect. Shouldn't this be the ip address of one of the google servers?

The displayed address is the address that rejected the used UDP probe (which is expected for the final destination). It's possible that it has bound the destination IP on one of its port but it's at least responding *on behalf* of the destination IP.